# why can't we use indirection operator with array name?

Tags: c

In the below code , why can't I dereference the array name ,since when an array is passed as an argument to a function , it becomes pointer to first element of the array , so why can't we dereference it then ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

    char s[] = "radha";
    int a[2] = {0,1};
    printf("%s ", *s);
    printf("%d", *a);
    return 0;
}
```

​
I am getting segmentation fault for the above code , what's the reason here , when I use a[0] ,it is internally converted as *(a+0) , so what's the issue in simply doing *a or *S ,please clarify .

Comment: `printf("%s ",*s);` -> `printf("%s ",s);`

Comment: `*s` == `s[0]` == `'r'`.  you want `printf("%s ", s);` or `printf("%c ", *s);`

Comment: Terrible question title, you should think of a better one.

Comment: "Why do I aggravate the customer if I show him a picture of a bike instead of the car be just bought?"

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two suggestions of your,

1. Read the documentation.

   - The `"%s"` specifier expects a pointer of `char`, you are passing a `char` which is then considered an integer and dereference as if it were a pointer causing UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR.

   If you read the documentation, and understand that `char[]` is converted to `char *` also that dereferencing a `char *` poitner will give you a `char`, then you would understand why this is wrong.
2. Enable compiler warnings. If you do so, then a warning telling you that you are passing the wrong type would save you a lot of time and let you learn more about how to invoke a given function.

   If you ignored the warning, it's even worse. You should never ignore a warning unless you know beforehand that the compiler will complain about something. If the warning was not expected, then it's very likely an error instead.

Comment: I got the mistake now , can you please explain is there any difference if we use char str[] and char *str in a function prototype .

Comment: For the function call, there is no difference. The reason is that `char[]` is automatically converted to `char *` when you pass it as a function parameter.

Answer (score 7):

`printf("%s ",*s);` expects second argument to be a pointer to string while you are passing `char 'r'` (dereferencing `s` gives you first array item as expected).